# Subversion on carbide

Tags: svn, symbian, carbide

I am using carbide for symbian developement there is plugins called subclipse but the issue is when i go to option of find and install under software updates the IDE gets hungs is there any other way to add plugins in carbide IDE 
Thnx in advance,
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The procedure to install `subclipse` on Carbide-2.0 is simple:

1. Get the "Eclipse update site URL"
   for the latest version of subclipse from
   the [subclipse download page](http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess;jsessionid=E9DC725D5582C7EE11562BF4F6BC67F7?pageID=p4wYuA);
2. Within Carbide, go to Help > Software Updates > Find and Install;
3. Select "search for new features to install";
4. Click on the "New Remote Site" button;
5. Add the URL from step 1;
6. Check the package and install away.

I am using `subclipse` on Carbide-2.0 without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a proxy to access the internet you need to configure the Eclipse proxy settings to access updates sites.

- go to Window > Preferences...
- in the search box on the top left type "proxy" to filter the set of preference panels.
- click on Network Connections
- enter your proxy settings
- try the update process again